# Meteor- projections on cursor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Currently, I have helpers on my collections (using dburles:collection-helpers).

For example, in my Teams collection, I have the following helper defined. I'm making use of this helper on the client:

```
getUnlockedProblems: function() {
    return Problems.find({requirements: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: this.getSolvedIds()}}}});
},
```

In my publications.js, I have a publication to publish a team's solved problems which essentially uses this same query, except filters out the `grader` field:

```
return Problems.find({requirements: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: team.getSolvedIds()}}}}, {fields: {grader: 0}});
```

Is there any way to do something like `return team.getUnlockedProblems().project({fields: {grader: 0}})` instead? So I can re-use the query

Comment: Is adding an `options` parameter to `getUnlockedProblems` an acceptable solution?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I guess that works. Not sure why i didnt think of doing that! thanks

Comment: Great. For completeness, I answerified my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection helpers are regular functions, so you can solve this by adding an `options` parameter to `getUnlockedProblems` like so:

```
getUnlockedProblems: function(options) {
  return Problems.find({requirements: ...}, options);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var team = Teams.findOne();

// Get a cursor with a limited set of fields
team.getUnlockedProblems({fields: {grader: 0}});

// Get a cursor with a complete set of fields
team.getUnlockedProblems();
```

Comment: Just to add on to this: I defined the function to use an optional parameter `getUnlockedProblems: function(options={}) {`, so I wouldn't need to rewrite my existing calls to it

Comment: I think that probably makes the code more clear, although in this case it isn't strictly necessary as `find(selector, undefined)` is the same as `find(selector)`.